# Copy a script value to Input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page counter that I want to put into a form input value. 
Here is the script:

```
<script id="counter">
if (localStorage.pagecount)
 {
 localStorage.pagecount=Number(localStorage.pagecount) +1;
 }
else
 {
 localStorage.pagecount=1;
 }
document.write(localStorage.pagecount);
</script>
```

And this is where I want it to go:

```
<input id="RR_No" type="text" size="10" name="RR_No" required>
```

But I don't know how to copy the value.

I'm really new to javascript so if you can reply with really simple answers that would really help.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('RR_No').value = localStorage.pagecount;
```

`document.getElementById` is used to find the DOM element with `id="RR_No"`. The `.value` property is used to set or retrieve the value of an input element.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `document.write` line with:

```js
document.getElementById('RR_No').value = localStorage.pagecount;
```

```html
<input id="RR_No" type="text" size="10" name="RR_No" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.write` write:

```
document.getElementById('RR_No').value = localStorage.pagecount
```

Checkout This DEMO: http://jsbin.com/komofe/1/